# I want to RotateRight a list of lists.

Tags: list-manipulation

I know how to `RotateRight` a single list; lets take the following example:

```
list=Range[5];
rot=RotateRight[list,2]
```

But how to make the same rotation on a bunch of lists like:

```
list={Range[5],Range[5]};
```

The result should look like:

```
rot={{4,5,1,2,3},{4,5,1,2,3}}
```

Comment: I vote to close this question as this can be quite easily found in the documentation for `RotateRight`and also [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NestedLists.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example

```
list = {Range[5], Range[5]};
RotateRight[#, 2] & /@ list
```

### Output

> `{{4, 5, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}}`

### Reference

[Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html?q=Map)
[Pure Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)

### Additional Resources

[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)
[What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for! Thank you! I will study the syntax, as I'm still a bit unfamiliar with '&' and '/@', though I know it means 'Function' and 'Map'...

Comment: @Key I will add a reference section covering those and some additional link to some useful information on the subject :) glad it was helpful

Answer (score 7):

For [`RotateRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateRight.html) you can specify levelspec by using a list in the 2nd argument:

```
list = {Range[5], Range[5]};
RotateRight[list, {0, 2}]
```

> `{{4, 5, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}}`

Comment: +1. This is imho the most concise answer to the question as no other constructs are needed to fulfill the task - `RotateRight` is well able to do it by itself given the right parametrization.

Comment: I agree with @gwr. I didn't think about giving a list as additional argument. Nice that this works... However, the general solution from e.doroskevic might be of interest too.

Comment: @gwr I think the reason for the diversity of answers is manifold. 1. the question must be asked properly (especially difficult for non-native speakers) 2. Sometimes the example given is just a MWE. The problem might be even more complicated. Thats why a general solution could be more useful. 3.

Comment: @Kay Sure, but you may see that this specific answer **is more general** than mapping `RotateRight` with one parameter? Sometimes it simply pays off to wait with an accept to give other solutions a chance - rather than to strive for *instant gratification*... :)

Comment: @gwr I'm sure *instant gratification* isn't possible for theat reason :D But thanks for your comments! I'll think about this

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `ConstantArray[]` directly

```
ConstantArray[RotateRight[Range[5], 2], 2]
```